# ¿Cómo refrescar un JTable con conexion a BD mediante JPA?

Tags: java, jpa, oracle-11g, eclipselink

Mi problema es el siguiente resulta que no logro refrescar el jtable para que los datos se actualicen ahí en cierta forma si lo logre cuando hago mis metodos de CRUD(create, actualizar, leer, eliminar) ahi si se actualiza la tabla(cabe recalcar que lo que acostumbro para refrescar es el comando setvisible para el CRUD) pero cuando trata de un procedimiento almacenado no lo consigo. El programa en si no arroja ningun error y el procedimiento se ejecuta bien en mi base de datos pero no se actualiza el jtable como cuando hacia mi CRUD. Ya intente varias formas una de ellas es limpiar el jtable y volverlo a cargar con un boton de refresh que vuelva a cargar el jtable pero sigo con el problema.

**Mi código es el siguiente. Este es el codigo de mi procedimiento almacenado**

```
 /// Actualizar articulos (procedimiento almacenado

EntityManagerFactory emf;
emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("ABARROTESPU");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
try{
em.getTransaction().begin();


//Creacion de procedimiento
StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedure = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("ACTCLIE");
//introduccion de parametros de tipo entrada
storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("p_id_cliente", Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN);
storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("p_nombre", String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("p_direccion", String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("p_tel", Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN);

//salida de infro de lo que se esta recabando
String id1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("introduce id");
String nombre= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Intruduce nombre");
String direc = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduce direccion");
String  tel = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduce telefono");

int id2= Integer.parseInt(id1);
int tel2= Integer.parseInt(tel);

storedProcedure.setParameter("p_id_cliente", id2);
storedProcedure.setParameter("p_nombre", nombre);
storedProcedure.setParameter("p_direccion", direc);
storedProcedure.setParameter("p_tel", tel2);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ingreso con exito"+ JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

storedProcedure.execute();

//        //igualar parametros a variable
//        Integer id = (Integer) storedProcedure.getParameterValue("xidArticulos");
//        Integer canti = (Integer) storedProcedure.getParameterValue("xcantidad");
//
//        //Realizar impresion de resultado
//        System.out.println("El id   " + id);
//        System.out.println("Cantidad es de: " + canti);

   this.Clear_Table1();


  em.getTransaction().commit();

   em.close();
 }


     catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("Error");
     }
```

**Este es el codigo de vaciado de jtable, de llenado y de creacion.**

```
          public static DefaultTableModel modelo4;

            private void CrearModelo5() { //Formato de tabla cliente
        try {
            modelo4 = (new DefaultTableModel(
                null, new String[]{
                "ID Cliente", "Nombre", "Direccion","Telefono"}
              ) {
        Class[] types = new Class[]{
            java.lang.String.class,
            java.lang.String.class,
            java.lang.String.class,
            java.lang.String.class
        };
        boolean[] canEdit = new boolean[]{
            false, false, false, false
        };

        @Override
        public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            return types[columnIndex];
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int colIndex) {
            return canEdit[colIndex];
        }
    });
    jTable1.setModel(modelo4);
     modelo4.fireTableDataChanged();
} catch (Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.toString() + "error2");
}
 }

    private void Carga(){ //Cargar datos en la tabla cliente
     try {
   Object a[]= null;
    List <Cliente> listP = cClie.findClienteEntities();

      for (int i = 0; i < listP.size(); i++)
        {
               modelo4.addRow(a);
             modelo4.setValueAt(listP.get(i).getIdCliente(), i, 0);
              modelo4.setValueAt(listP.get(i).getNombre(), i, 1);
                modelo4.setValueAt(listP.get(i).getDireccion(), i, 2);
               modelo4.setValueAt(listP.get(i).getTelefono(), i, 3);

                      }

            } catch (Exception e) {
               System.out.println("no hay informacion");
                } 
                }
```

**Codigo de limpia jtable**

```
 private void Clear_Table1() { // Limpiar rows jtable 
for (int i = 0; i < jTable1.getRowCount(); i++) {
    modelo4.removeRow(i);
    i -= 1;
}
 }
```

***Cabe recalcar que estoy usando la libreria de EclipseLink, mi gestor de base de datos es oracle 11g***

---

### Esta el la clase donde mapeo la tabla clientes de mi Base de datos.

```
package Entidades;

import javax.persistence.Id;import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;
```

/

```
**
 *
 * @author HP-central
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "CLIENTE")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Cliente.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM Cliente c"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Cliente.findByIdCliente", query = "SELECT c FROM Cliente c WHERE c.idCliente = :idCliente"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Cliente.findByNombre", query = "SELECT c FROM Cliente c WHERE c.nombre = :nombre"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Cliente.findByDireccion", query = "SELECT c FROM Cliente c WHERE c.direccion = :direccion"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Cliente.findByTelefono", query = "SELECT c FROM Cliente c WHERE c.telefono = :telefono")})
public class Cliente implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "ID_CLIENTE")
    private Integer idCliente;
    @Column(name = "NOMBRE")
    private String nombre;
    @Column(name = "DIRECCION")
    private String direccion;
    @Column(name = "TELEFONO")
    private Long telefono;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "idCliente")
    private List<Articulos> articulosList;
public Cliente() {
}

public Cliente(Integer idCliente) {
    this.idCliente = idCliente;
}

public Integer getIdCliente() {
    return idCliente;
}

public void setIdCliente(Integer idCliente) {
    this.idCliente = idCliente;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getDireccion() {
    return direccion;
}

public void setDireccion(String direccion) {
    this.direccion = direccion;
}

public Long getTelefono() {
    return telefono;
}

public void setTelefono(Long telefono) {
    this.telefono = telefono;
}

@XmlTransient
public List<Articulos> getArticulosList() {
    return articulosList;
}

public void setArticulosList(List<Articulos> articulosList) {
    this.articulosList = articulosList;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (idCliente != null ? idCliente.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
    if (!(object instanceof Cliente)) {
        return false;
    }
    Cliente other = (Cliente) object;
    if ((this.idCliente == null && other.idCliente != null) || (this.idCliente != null && !this.idCliente.equals(other.idCliente))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Entidades.Cliente[ idCliente=" + idCliente + " ]";
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mi primera sugerencia es que verifiques con tu consulta a traves de JPA, realmente te estas trayendo los datos de la base de datos....Si estas usando la forma CRUD supongo que debe haber una clase que mapea la tabla que estas consultando.....por lo que tambien te animo a guardarlo en un

```
List<Usuarios> usuarios = new ArrayList();
```

por ejemplo.

Segundo crea una clase que solo se dedique a manipular el JTable.
revisa este ejemplo, tiene de todo un poco:

```
public class configuracion_tablas extends JLabel implements TableCellRenderer{



public void configuracion_alternativa(JTable tabla, DefaultTableModel modelo, String columna, int ancho, String alineacion){


   DefaultTableCellRenderer alinear = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
   tabla.getColumn(columna).setCellRenderer(alinear);
   TableColumn tc1 = tabla.getColumn(columna);


   //System.out.println("Analisis antes: min:"+tc1.getMinWidth()+" max:"+tc1.getMaxWidth()+" preferido:"+tc1.getPreferredWidth()+" actual:"+tc1.getWidth()+" quiero:"+ancho);
   tabla.setAutoResizeMode(1);
   tc1.setMinWidth(ancho-1);//estableciendo el minimo
   tc1.setPreferredWidth(ancho+1);//estableciendo el preferido
   tc1.setWidth(ancho);//estableciendo el ancho real

    if(alineacion.equalsIgnoreCase("centrado")){//tc1.setPreferredWidth(ancho);
    alinear.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);}
    if(alineacion.equalsIgnoreCase("izquierda")){//tc1.setPreferredWidth(ancho);
    alinear.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);}
    if(alineacion.equalsIgnoreCase("derecha")){//tc1.setPreferredWidth(ancho);
    alinear.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);}

   System.out.println("Analisis despues: min:"+tc1.getMinWidth()+" max:"+tc1.getMaxWidth()+" preferido:"+tc1.getPreferredWidth()+" actual:"+tc1.getWidth()+" quiero:"+ancho);




 }

 public void configuracion(JTable tabla, DefaultTableModel modelo, String columna, int ancho, String alineacion){


   DefaultTableCellRenderer alinear = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
   tabla.getColumn(columna).setCellRenderer(alinear);
   TableColumn tc1 = tabla.getColumn(columna);


    if(alineacion.equalsIgnoreCase("centrado")){tc1.setPreferredWidth(ancho); alinear.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);}
    if(alineacion.equalsIgnoreCase("izquierda")){tc1.setPreferredWidth(ancho);alinear.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);}
    if(alineacion.equalsIgnoreCase("derecha")){tc1.setPreferredWidth(ancho); alinear.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);}



}

public void tabla_habilitadas(JTable tabla, LinkedList datos){

materias materia= new materias();


DefaultTableModel informacion = new DefaultTableModel(new Object [][] {},new String [] {"SEMESTRE","CODIGO","MATERIA","CONDICION"}){
    Class[] types = new Class [] {
    java.lang.Integer.class, java.lang.Object.class, java.lang.Object.class, java.lang.Object.class
};
boolean[] canEdit = new boolean [] {
    false, false, false, false
};

public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
    return types [columnIndex];
}

public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    return canEdit [columnIndex];
}
                                                                                                                                };




tabla.setModel(informacion);//estableciendo a la tabla que use el modelo llamado informacion

 for(int i=0; i<datos.size(); i=i+4){//recorriendo el LinkedList

     Object ingreso[]={Integer.valueOf(datos.get(i+3).toString()),//  columna semestre
                      datos.get(i), //columna codigo
                      datos.get(i+1), //columna materia
                      materia.condicion_materia(datos.get(i+2).toString()) //columna condicion
    };
     informacion.addRow(ingreso);
     informacion.fireTableDataChanged();

tabla.setAutoCreateColumnsFromModel(false);
tabla.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);


 }//fin recorricdo del LinkedList

}//fin metodo de autorizadas

public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

if (isSelected) {
/* Para celdas seleccionadas:
según el valor de 'value', pones el color, el tipo de letra,
el formato, o incluso el tooltip.
*/
setForeground(Color.BLUE);
//setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
setBackground(Color.BLUE);

} else {
/* Para celdas no seleccionadas:
según el valor de 'value', pones el color, el tipo de letra,
el formato, o incluso el tooltip.
*/
setForeground(table.getForeground());
setBackground(Color.RED);
setBackground(Color.RED);
}

setText("andy");

return this;

}




/**Este metodo permite dar color al texto segun codigo html incrustado para facilidad. 
 para ello hay que llenar ciertas caracteristicas, el color debe ser en formato hexadecimal
 como por ejemplo "#CD5C5C". El texto se devuelve formateado segun lo deseado*/
public String atributos_texto(String texto, String color, boolean negritas, boolean cursiva, boolean tachar){
    String armado = null;

//por defecto
armado = "<html>";        
//opciones    
if(negritas)armado = armado.concat("<b>");
if(cursiva)armado = armado.concat("<i>");
if(tachar)armado = armado.concat("<s>");
//incrustando todos los atributos

    armado = armado.concat("<font color="+color+">"+texto);//linea principal

//cerrando todo el codigo
if(negritas)armado = armado.concat("</b>");
if(cursiva)armado = armado.concat("</i>");
if(tachar)armado = armado.concat("</s>");

armado = armado.concat("</html>");

texto = armado;
/*
texto="<html><font color="+color+">"+texto+"</font></html>"; //color    
texto="<html><b><font color="+color+">"+texto+"</font></b></html>"; //negrita
texto="<html><i><font color="+color+">"+texto+"</font></i></html>"; //cursiva
texto="<html><s><font color="+color+">"+texto+"</s></i></html>"; //tachar
*/

return texto;
}


public static void main(String [] args){

    configuracion_tablas ct = new configuracion_tablas();
   System.out.println( ct.atributos_texto("andy","#011400", true, true, true));

}







}//fin de la clase
```

Comment: No comprendo tu explicación ya que mi jtable tiene sus propio metodos que son los que plasmo en mi pregunta me a servido cuando realizo CRUD por ejemplo cuando insertaba bastaba con que pusiera un setvisible (false) en seguida de un setvisible(true y automaticamente funcionaba pero cuando realizo hice este procedimiento almacenado que sirve para insertar pues funciona pero no logro que se actualize en el jtable tengo que recargar el programa volviendo a compilar.

Comment: Una manera de actualizar el JTable es insertarle con cada lote de información un DefaulTableModel nuevo que es quien retiene los datos. Porque lo que entiendo que cuando ingresas datos nuevos el jtable no actualiza la vista, por lo cual no puedes ver la nueva información ingresada. Aclárame esa parte porque si es lo que pienso se como apoyarte.

Comment: Umm osea que me sugieres hacer un DefaulTableModel nuevo aparte del que ya tengo(si es asi ¿Cómo?) que este.  public static DefaultTableModel modelo4; Te reitero antes conseguia actualizar cuando utilizaba los controladores del jpa para CRUD bastaba nomas con con un setvisible(false) y luego true para refrescar la interfaz. Pero ahora que intento con procedimientos almacenados no lo consigo por ese método. Y si tienes razon LO QUE NO SE ACTUALIZA ES LA VISTA ya que mi base de datos si sufre cambios con exito.

Comment: Bueno hay cosas del JTable que no entendí completamente en su tiempo cuando lo utilice, pero algo con lo que pude resolver fue crear una nueva instancia .....claro esta que la misma tiene que tener la estructura que aparece en el JFrame....prácticamente es copiar y pegar....cada vez que quería colocar un lote de información y que se viera cuando intentaba reutilizarla fue  creando un New DefaulTableModel para poderlo hacer visible porque me sucedía lo mismo que a ti....este Default tiene siempre la misma estructura....luego lo rellenas de los datos nuevamente. Claro actualmente uso JavaFX8

Comment: Pues lo intente y sigo sin poder resolver mi problema.

Comment: David haz una cosa.....mira olvidate por un momento del proyecto y descansa al menos 1 hora.....luego trata de hacer una clase aparte que solo se encargue de llenar un JTable y que esta solo reciba como parametro un List<>, de esta manera logras desacoplar todo y seguramente desaparezca tu problema porque muchas veces son tonterias y con tanto codigo junto no se ve a simple vista....eso me sucedio mucho con demasiado...es la mejor recomendacion que te puedo dar....!!! pero primero refrezca la mente porque sino no te va a servir de nada!!!